# PHP file download with symlinks

Tags: php, download, symlink

I have a bunch of .tgz files that are made accessible via. symlinks. When I click on the `href` on my page pointing to the symlink, it downloads a rather strange file. The downloaded file has the name of the symlink, and upon opening the archive I get (from what I can tell) a binary file, which may or may not be to contents of the static file.

What I'd like to do is get PHP to show a file download dialogue that gives the file linked by the symlink, not the actual symlink. Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well to give you an exact answer I would need to know more about how you serve the file.
Why is php even involved? isn't the file served by the webserver? Do you redirect to it or read it into memory in your php script from where you print it?

But I can tell you this.

PHP does in most cases handle symlinks as files, and doesn't samlessly serve the file behind the link.

There are the php functions is_link() to check if a resource pointer is a link,
there is the function readlink() to serve the file behind a link and there is linkinfo() which gives you information about the link.

But most likely you need to explicitly allow Apache or whatever server you are using to follow symlinks which can be dyne witht he `Options FollowSymLinks` directive in apache.

Comment: Yup, Options FollowSymLinks seems suspiciously

Comment: Thanks Joe. I eventually worked it out by using this line to read the file, after passing some `header()` parameters: `readfile(readlink("path/to/symlink"));`

Comment: I tried using the Apache configuration switch, but to no avail.

Comment: so its working now or are you still having proglems? if so i could have a please set your apache loglevel to debug and send us the output...

Answer (score 1):

PHP has [readlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readlink.php) that allow you get the path that it targeted/linked to.
However, think your problem is related to apache rewrite, or absolute path (again)

**PS :** did tgz extensions supported by your apache mime?

refer : http://www.w3schools.com/media/media_mimeref.asp